# QLabel vs QTextEdit, to show long text. Which is faster?

Tags: performance, qt, qtextedit, qlabel

I used `QTextEdit` in read-only mode (I want to make it become Label) to show a **long text**, but I wonder that when doing like this, how is our performance? Will `QTextEdit` be faster than `QLabel` or not? Is there any better ways to show a long text and to get a good performance? Please help me answer these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't have rich text and want to only show plain text, it's better to use [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) which is exactly for showing large texts. It uses most of the features of `QTextEdit` but with a vastly better performance.

Using `QPlainTextEdit` is better than using `QLabel` for displaying large text documents as the former has many more capabilities and features for customization and formatting.

Comment: Side note: Any kind of `QTextEdit`, including `QPlainTextEdit` is abysmally small if you intend to periodically update it. For things such as updating logs, roll your own or use `QTableView` and a suitable model.